# Should we use BEM(Block, Element, Modifier) in react styled component

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, bem

I am working with react styled component. Should we use BEM(Block, Element, Modifier) in styled component ? If yes then how ?

I tried to give `ClassName` but its not working

```
import { SiteHeader } from './site-header';

export const SiteHeaderStyled = styled(SiteHeader).attrs({
 className: 'SiteHeader',
 })`
   &__nav {
     color: red;
   }
 `;
```

Comment: I edited my answer, does it help you ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's on your own, you could only use styled-components to define every node that needs style, or you could mix the two: use styled-components + inline style, styled-components for component container + classname for inner nodes (with style defined in the styled container), or even mix these 3 approaches depending on the case.

In every case, if you stick with styled-component, you don't need BEM because everything is, at least, scoped to only 1 component

EDIT: response to your edit

What's not working ? style on SiteHeaderStyled (.SiteHeader) or on the nav child ?

The `&__nav` can't work because there is no parent (in the scss code part), you have to wrap it like this:

```
export const SiteHeaderStyled = styled(SiteHeader).attrs({
 className: 'SiteHeader',
 })`
   .SiteHeader {
     &__nav {
       color: red;
     }
   }
 `;
```

**By using above is coming like screenshot** [image]
in any case, if it's a project where you use styled-component everywhere, something like this is should be sufficient:

```
import { SiteHeader } from './site-header';

export const SiteHeaderStyled = styled(SiteHeader)`
   .nav {
     color: red;
   }
 `;
```

Comment: How we can give meaning full name to styled component then ? beacuse it uses default css name ?

Comment: @AshwaniPanwar you could give the default className you should have given with no styled-component/BEM. Since the styled-components you gonna define in a component file are scoped in file/component, you don't have to worry about 
redundancy

Comment: I tried but its not working, please check question I updated.

Comment: Actually className `SiteHeader` and `nav` is not coming out. Basically I want to give class  name to wrapper so that it could be easily identify and I can put css for this.

Comment: @AshwaniPanwar just replace .SiteHeader1 by .SideHeader, was a typo